# Remove stored data from sharedpreferences at the start of another day in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have an app I am working on. I used sharedpreferences and provider to store the index of the pageview of the screen so that when I click on a button from the home page, it navigates to the PageViewScreen and will continue from the last index page of the pageView screen I was before leaving the app. However I want to make the app to start from the first index if the date changes to another date.

To explain further, If user opens the app 28th of January in the morning, I would love to store the last page index they were on before leaving the app. If user then come back in the afternoon, I would want that they continue from where they stop. However if the time changes to 29th of January  from exactly 12am, I want to clear the data saved in sharedpreferences so that they can start from first index.

I understand that I will use sharedpreference clear or remove method but I do not understand how to track each day so I can use the method.

I have created the code to save the last index but remains how to clear the last index for every date change.

here is my provider and shared preference file

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class ProviderData extends ChangeNotifier {
  SharedPreferences? prefs;
  final String pageIndexKey = 'pageIndex';
  int? _pageIndex;

  ProviderData() {
    _pageIndex = 0;
    loadFromPrefs();
  }

  _initPrefs() async {
    prefs ??= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  loadFromPrefs() async {
    await _initPrefs();
    _pageIndex = prefs!.getInt(pageIndexKey) ?? 0;
    notifyListeners();
    return _pageIndex;
  }

  _savePageIndexToPrefs({required String key, required int value}) async {
    await _initPrefs();
    prefs!.setInt(key, value);
  }

  void changePageIndex(int newPageIndex) {
    _pageIndex = newPageIndex;

    _savePageIndexToPrefs(key: pageIndexKey, value: _pageIndex!);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

below is my PageViewScreen file,

I use Future builder to get my last index so I can build my app based on the last index

```
Future getProvider() {
 return ProviderData().loadFromPrefs().then((value) {
   return PageController(initialPage: value - 1);
 });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
     body: FutureBuilder(
         future: getProvider(),
         builder: ((context, snapshot) {
           if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
             if (snapshot.hasError) {
               return Center(
                   child: Text(
                 '${snapshot.error} occurred',
                 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
               ));
             } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
               final control = snapshot.data;

               return Stack(
                 children: [
                   Consumer<ProviderData>(
                     builder: (context, providerData, _) {
                       return PageView(
                         controller: control,
                         onPageChanged: (index) {

           ///// I saved the index of the pageview here but I would love to clear it and make it start from index1 for every new date i.e 12am of everyday.


                           providerData.changePageIndex(index);

                           // setState(() {
                           //   onLastPage = index == 2;
                           //   onFirstPage = index == 0;
                           //   onSecondPage = index == 1;
                           //   onThirdPage = index == 2;
                           //   onFourthPage = index == 3;
                           //   onFifthPage = index == 4;
                           //   onSixthPage = index == 5;
                           //   onSeventhPage = index == 6;
                           // });
                         },
                         children: _pageList,
                       );
                     },
                   ),
                   Align(
                     alignment: Alignment(0, -0.8),
                     child: Consumer<ProviderData>(
                         builder: (context, providerData, _) {
                       return SmoothPageIndicator(
                         controller: control,
                         count: 13,
                         effect: SlideEffect(
                             activeDotColor: Color.fromRGBO(215, 60, 16, 1)),
                       );
                     }),
                   ),
                   Align(
                     alignment: Alignment(0, 0.5),
                     child: Row(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                       children: [
                         GestureDetector(
                           onTap: (() {
                             control.previousPage(
                                 duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                 curve: Curves.easeIn);
                           }),
                           child: Text(
                             "prev",
                             style: TextStyle(
                                 fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 16),
                           ),
                         ),
                         GestureDetector(
                           onTap: (() {
                             control.nextPage(
                                 curve: Curves.easeIn,
                                 duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
                           }),
                           child: Text(
                             "Next",
                             style: TextStyle(
                                 fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 16),
                           ),
                         ),
                       ],
                     ),
                   )
                 ],
               );
             }
           }
           return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
         }
         )
         )
         );
}
```

Please I need someone that can help me solve and approach this issue.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the date of last change inside the Shared Preferences, and to check it every time when you load the preferences. It's important to keep the date without time and minutes, so recreating the date during the same day will have the same value.

You can simplify the provider logic and only use it as Provider instead of ChangeNotifier.

Here is a working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(
    Provider(
      create: (context) => ProviderData(sharedPrefs),
      child: const MainApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  final _pages = [
    const Center(
      child: Text(
        'Page 1',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 38),
      ),
    ),
    const Center(
      child: Text(
        'Page 2',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 38),
      ),
    ),
    const Center(
      child: Text(
        'Page 3',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 38),
      ),
    ),
    const Center(
      child: Text(
        'Page 4',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 38),
      ),
    ),
  ];
  late final PageController _pageController;
  late final ProviderData _providerData;
  bool loading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.scheduleFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _providerData = context.read<ProviderData>();
      _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _providerData.getPageIndex());
      setState(() => loading = false);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: loading
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Scaffold(
              body: Stack(
                children: [
                  PageView(
                    controller: _pageController,
                    children: _pages,
                    onPageChanged: (value) => _providerData.savePageIndexToPrefs(value: value),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: const Alignment(0, -0.8),
                    child: SmoothPageIndicator(
                      controller: _pageController,
                      count: _pages.length,
                      effect: const SlideEffect(activeDotColor: Color.fromRGBO(215, 60, 16, 1)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: const Alignment(0, 0.5),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (() {
                            _pageController.previousPage(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeIn);
                          }),
                          child: const Text(
                            "Prev",
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (() {
                            _pageController.nextPage(curve: Curves.easeIn, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
                          }),
                          child: const Text(
                            "Next",
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}

class ProviderData {
  ProviderData(this._prefs);

  final SharedPreferences _prefs;
  static const String _pageIndexKey = 'pageIndex';
  static const String _pageIndexLastUpdated = 'pageIndexLastUpdatedKey';

  int getPageIndex() {
    final lastUpdatedStr = _prefs.getString(_pageIndexLastUpdated);
    if (lastUpdatedStr != null) {
      final lastUpdated = DateTime.parse(lastUpdatedStr);
      final now = DateTime.now();
      // creating a date without hours and minutes
      final today = DateTime.utc(now.year, now.month, now.day);
      if (lastUpdated.isAtSameMomentAs(today)) {
        final pageIndex = _prefs.getInt(_pageIndexKey) ?? 0;

        return pageIndex;
      }
    }

    _prefs.remove(_pageIndexKey);

    return 0;
  }

  void savePageIndexToPrefs({required int value}) {
    _prefs.setInt(_pageIndexKey, value);
    final now = DateTime.now();
    // creating a date without hours and minutes
    final today = DateTime.utc(now.year, now.month, now.day);
    _prefs.setString(_pageIndexLastUpdated, today.toIso8601String());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to help me out. However, in the loadFromPrefs function, I have an error that says "A value of type 'int? can't be returned from the method 'loadFromPrefs' because it has a return type of 'Future<int>' ' ".  when I change it to Future<int?>, I was forced to go and use ! at the front of value in my Future in futureBuilder.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to help me out. However, in the loadFromPrefs function, I have an error that says "A value of type 'int? can't be returned from the method 'loadFromPrefs' because it has a return type of 'Future<int> in _pageIndex return' ' ".  when I change it to Future<int?>, I was forced to go and use ! at the front of value in my getProvider function in futureBuilder. Please kindly help me to look at the getProvider() function in future builder. Is that the correct thing to return? because I still cannot get the last index to work. I hopefully await your response. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome! I've updated my comment, so loadFromPrefs method should return a Future<int> because it always going to be not null.
May I ask you why do you initialize the page controller with the previous page rather than the saved? PageController(initialPage: value - 1);

And you are still not able to reset the index on next day?

Comment: Thank you for updating the code. I'm sorry, I just thought of it that I am supposed to return the saved date. I have not been able to check if the code will reset the index on the next day. However it is not storing the last index if on thesame day. The code starts all over from the first index after coming back to the app. Please kindly help check how I saved the index in pageView onPageChanged function. I am also thinking it  could be that the loadFromPrefs is only reading the last code i.e _pageIndex = 0 and neglecting the if condition, maybe that's why it is starting all over.

Comment: Yeah you are right. The condition must be reversed or to use isAtSameMomentAs. I've updated my comment. Let me know is that change works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. But the app still start all over. I just thought of what I want to achieve and I think it is best to not use it in loadFromPrefs. The approach is that the user's time should be saved to sharedpreferences on page load and it should be compared to the time they are coming back to the app next. then if on page load the day is still thesame, they should continue from the last index otherwise start again. So I am thinking of using initState but I still don't know the right approach. Please can you help if you understand my explanation?. Thank you

Comment: Check my example in the updated answer.

Comment: Thank You so much for taking time to help me out. I have followed your code and I have been able to save and retrieve the last index. However I still use the changeNotifier because I have Multiprovider and three changeNofierProvider wrapping my main file so I am not able to just use the provider. I am really amazed at your approach to solving questiions. I really do appreciate your kind help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hello, The date time just changed here and I tried to confirm if the index will clear and it did clear. However the sharedpreference stops saving the last index because of the WidgetsBinding. I tried removing the widgetbinding but it won't still work. What I really want to achieve is that the last index should be saved for 24hrs and be cleared daily and not once. I am trying to build an app that will allow users to come and repeat thesame thing everyday and that's the reason I want it to be a continuous process. I am so sorry for the stress I am giving. I don't know if that is possible?

Comment: Hello, It should check the saved date stamp agains today's stamp every time when the widget is initialized, and if it's old, It's going to delete the saved index. Also it should save the index and date stamp when current page changes. Am I not understanding? What's the problem with the shared prefs?

Comment: Hello, Yes I understand you. However, there are some issues if I am to follow your code. One of them is that I have more than one provider that use changenotifier in my app, another one is that my app builds before I am able to get the value of my index from providerData, so I always have lateInitialization error for my pageController. Please check this github repo "https://github.com/oluwajueda/appdemo". I have narrowed the structure of the app to contain my problem alone. The pageview is not directly in the main.dart. there is a button that leads to the pageview page in my home page.

Comment: So on click of the button that leads to the pageView, the app loads immediately without waiting for the providerData, so I get late initialization error. That is why I use futureBuilder to get the value before build. I would be grateful if you can help me check the source code and correct the code and achieve what I want to achieve, I have spent more than three weeks trying to fix this issue. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Hey, I've checked the code and here is what you can do to make it works:
1) pageView.dart line 51: return PageController(initialPage: value);. 2) provider_data.dart line line 79: prefs!.setString("**pageIndexLastUpdatedKey**", today.toIso8601String());

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me,  I have fixed it with your correction.

Comment: Yes, I just did...I'm so sorry, I would have done that since. I am new to asking questions on stackoverflow and I just got to know with your request.